# Shopware Elastic exact Serach Phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware

When i search "Tentagel xv" i get back all product tenatgel and xv, but i just want the products

https://shopware.dev.rapp.4c.media/search?search=tentagel+xv

It jeust work wehen i search for xv- tentagel
https://shopware.dev.rapp.4c.media/search?search=xv-+tentagel

but no one customer searches like this.

how can i fix this?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: Probably you are using match query, instead you can use match_phrase_prefix query to achieve that. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html